# Compiling script with lingpipe

Tags: java, lingpipe

I have ubuntu installed on my pc and downloaded ant and linpipe (Desktop). Now I have written a training data set to train my classifier but I am not able to crack how to compile the code. Help me !!

Answer (score 0):

There is a support document detailing how to install LingPipe at: http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/install.html#instLingPipe

The simplest classification tutorial is at:

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html

If you need more help and details I suggest you get our book "Natural Language Processing with Java and LingPipe Cookbook" since it is written at the simplest level.